# display json on android

Tags: java, android

I want to have a time using `SimpleDateFormat` but i always have errors and i don't know why?

This is my code:

```
package com.mobiblanc.wydadnews.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.net.ParseException;

public class Article implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String title;
    private String excerpt;
    private String content;
    private String  pubdate;

    public String getDate() {

        return pubdate;

        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        try {


            this.pubdate=fmt.format(pubdate);



        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace(); 

        }

    }


    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.pubdate = date;

    }



    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getExcerpt() {
        return excerpt;
    }

    public void setExcerpt(String excerpt) {
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error? please share the logcat logs..

Comment: please add error, and also input.

Comment: what exactly do you expect getDate() to do? (java101 (programing101, actually) : return is usually the last statement executed in a method.)

Answer (score 1):

What i see is, your getDate method() always return the date before calling  SimpleDateFormat.

```
public String getDate() {

    return pubdate; // this returns date; remove it

    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {


        this.pubdate=fmt.format(pubdate);



    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace(); 

    }

}
```

Comment: great attention 2 detail dude +1

Comment: yes for " return pubdate" ; i made a mistak it will not be there , my code is like this 

private String title;
 private String excerpt;
 private String content;
 private String  pubdate;


 @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
 
 
 public String getDate() { 


  SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");
  
  try {
   this.pubdate = fmt.format(pubdate);


  } catch (ParseException e) {


   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }



  return pubdate;

 }